# session.invalidate実行後の、jsp:includeが動作しません

Tags: html, jsp, session

現在下記のような実装になっています

```html
<% session.invalidate(); %>

<html>

    <head>～</head>

    <body>

        <jsp:include flush="true" page="ｘｘｘ.jsp"/>

    </body>

</html>
```

この状態だとjsp:includeが動作していないようで、画面にはｘｘｘ.jspが表示されておりません。

しかし、以下のように実装を変えると、正常にjsp:includeが動作し、画面にはｘｘｘ.jspが表示されております。

```
<html>

    <head>～</head>

    <body>

        <jsp:include flush="true" page="ｘｘｘ.jsp"/>

    </body>

</html>

<% session.invalidate(); %>
```

上記事象より、includeが正常動作しない理由はsession.invalidateだと考えられるのですが、何故session.invalidate(セッション削除)によってjsp:includeが動作しなくなるのかが分かりません。

分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<jsp:include flush="true">`をすると、サーブレットコンテナは指定したJSPをインクルードする前にレスポンスを出力しようと試みます。

また、インクルード前に`session.invalidate();`をしているため、インクルード先のJSPを読み込むときに、新たにsessionを生成しようとします。
しかし一度レスポンスを出力しようとした後にsessionを生成することはコンテナの仕様にも依るところですが、基本的にサーブレットの例外となりできません。

対策としては、以下のどちらか2つで可能です。

1. `<jsp:include>`のflush属性をつけない。
2. flush属性をつけるときは、インクルードするJSPのpageディレクティブにて、セッションを利用しない宣言をする。
   `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" session="false" %>`

Comment: ご返答ありがとう御座います。
ご返答より、問題を解決することが出来ました。